# Rails - creating new instances of other classes when new user created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller

I am trying to have it so that when a new user is created in the app, everything is already set up for them. E.g. they have a folder, which they save notes in to. So, rather than having to click on a link to a new folder, then a submit button to create it, before they can save any notes, is it possible to set one up for them automatically when their user account is created?

E.g.

users_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @user.password = params[:password]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
         @folder = @user.folder.new(params[:folder]) # this is the line that I'm unsure how to implement

        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

SOLUTION:

As I am using Devise, the routing I was adding to my users controller was getting overridden, so the solution (there are probably better ways to do this!) was to add the code to the after_user_sign_up_path in the registrations controller, then it executes fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your action you use params both for `@user` and `@user.folder`.

I would advice to use [nested_attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

```
class User
  has_one :folder
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :folder
end
```

Then you can write your action this way:

```
def create
  @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      # Here the folder is already saved!

      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The should have many advantages (although I haven't checked them all), among them:

- don't risk to save a `@user` without a folder (if folder saving fails, user saving fails)
- @user.errors should contain both validation errors of `@user` and `@user.folder`

But to do that, you should have a different structure for your params (which is easy to achieve with [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)):

```
user:
  password: "Any password"
  folder_attributes:
    any_attribute: "Any value"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, looks like it will simplify the process - however, the user is getting saved, but not a new folder? I am using Devise for user authentication, so could it be that the registrations controller is overriding it somewhere? Although, the only contents of the registrations controller is after_sign_in_path etc. I haven't changed anything to use fields_for yet though - do I need to do that to get the nested_attributes to work? Thanks!

Comment: I've accepted this answer as I think it will do what I want for most applications - however, in this case I used an alternative solution which I've added to the original question in case anyone has a similar problem to me.